# Which algorithm in Deep learning can verfity the relationship of column into a matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm reading these days about deep learning and its utilization and the methods we can use it. I had a general question regarding the image verification or let's say a simple matrix.

Suppose I have a matrix of size `X = (4,4)` and a vector of size `Y = (1,4)`, I multiplied the the vector `Y` by only one column from `X`, let's say the second column. Hence, `Z = Y.*X(:,2)`. Suppose I know the matrix `X` and resulted vector `Z`, can I use the deep learning to verify which column from `X` was multiplied based on `Z` and `X` ?

I know, we can all simply use Maximum likehood decoder, or by divided X/Z ; In reality I need to avoid these conventional ways and go to deep learning. Can we do that using deep learning? which algorithm can be used in that case ?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why you want to solve a mathematical formula, which can be solved with 100% accuracy with a deep learning model? I don't get it

Comment: @PV8 in big data, using the Maximum likelihood or division will increase the complexity too much, so we are looking for a way with low complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can all simply use DNN, however the results are not that good compared with ML but there is no way to solve that.